# Set input on a specific cell I clicked on

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm building this user database where I have ID, Name, Email, Comments and 2 buttons for Delete and Edit in each cell in a React-boostrap Table.

I want to set input tags on the Name,Email and Comments when I click the Edit button on it cell, I was able to do that but the issue is each time the Edit button is clicked, it sets the input on all the cells instead of the specific cell I clicked.

My JSX code

```
return (
    <>
        <Table bordered hover>
            <thead>
            <tr className="text-center">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            {
                modifiedData.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Fragment key={item.id}>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                                <td>{editRow ? <Form.Control type="text" placeholder={item.name}/> : item.name}</td>
                                <td>{editRow ? <Form.Control type="text" placeholder={item.email}/> : item.email}</td>
                                <td>{editRow ? <Form.Control as="textarea" placeholder={item.comment}/> : item.comment}</td>
                                <td className="d-flex justify-content-md-evenly">
                                    {
                                        !editRow &&
                                        <Button
                                            style={{width: "75px"}}
                                            variant="danger"
                                            type="submit" onClick={() => Delete(index)}
                                        >
                                            Delete
                                        </Button>
                                    }
                                    {
                                        editRow ? <EditableCell/> : // I want this function to only run on the specific index, to change the "Name", "Email", and "Comment" areas to inputTags but on the specific cell without affecting the rest of the cells
                                            <Button
                                                style={{width: "75px"}}
                                                className="ms-1"
                                                variant="secondary"
                                                onClick={() => Edit(item.id)}>
                                                Edit
                                            </Button>
                                    }
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </Fragment>
                    )
                })
            }
            </tbody>

        </Table>
    </>
)
```

The Editable input tags that get called once the Edit button is clicked

```
function EditableCell() {
    return (
        <>
            <Button
                style={{width: "75px"}}
                variant="secondary"
            >
                Save
            </Button>
            <Button
                style={{width: "75px"}}
                variant="warning"
                onClick={cancelUpdate}
            >
                Cancel
            </Button>
        </>
    )
}
```

My Edit function

```
function Edit(itemID) {

    setEditRow(true)

}
```

My hooks variable

```
const [grid, setGrid] = useState([])
const [editRow, setEditRow] = useState(false)
```

I had to modify the little of the data I get from the API

```
const modifiedData = grid.map(({body, ...item}) => ({
    ...item,
    key: item.id,
    comment: body
}))
```

Comment: `HTMLElement.focus()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because all items are depend on one boolean state, I suggest using state depending on the `item id` and checking depending on that too.

```
{
  editRow === item.id ? <EditableCell/> : 
    <Button
      style={{width: "75px"}}
      className="ms-1"
      variant="secondary"
      onClick={() => Edit(item.id)}>
        Edit
    </Button>
}
```

And on the `Edit` function you need to pass the `item id`

```
function Edit(itemID) {
   setEditRow(itemID)
}
```

And you can do the same for delete.

Comment: Just tried this now but it didn't solve  my initial problem, I can't still wrap my head around it

Comment: Could you create an example on any live editor like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Comment: @TombrownAnuma, I think you didn't save before fork and share, please make sure you saved the files.

Comment: Please do the favour of checking it out again, sorry for the late response. https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-leavitt-mqxxf9?file=/package.json

the URL https://mqxxf9.csb.app/

Comment: I just figured it out with just a little deep thinking from your suggestion. I only had to add "editRow === item.id" to every boolean state. Once again Thanks a lot you can add any alternate suggestion from my implementation, I'm still a newbie on this. Thanks.